# Both squares aren't showing up on the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

This is my code:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function draw() {      
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(200, 0, 0)";
        context.fillRect(50, 50, 0, 0);
};

draw();
```

When I run it, I get no errors but it doesn't add the squares to the canvas. Can someone tell me why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre]. Why are you checking `if (canvas.getContext)`? You’re using `context` already, which means you already had to do `const context = canvas.getContext("2d");` somewhere, before this check.

Comment: `context.fillRect(50, 50, 0, 0);` will never draw anything; it’s a rectangle of zero width and zero height. `context.fillRect(0, settings.height, settings.width, 50);` will draw starting from `settings.height` as a position of the Y-axis. If `settings.height` is your canvas height, this will always be off-screen. Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second Rectangle does not have a height and width.
the function has the parameters `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` -> `fillRect(x, y, width, height)`.

Your line `context.fillRect(50, 50, 0, 0);` creates a box with width and height of 0 at 50px from x and y.

```js
const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
const settings = {x: 50, y: 50, height: 50, width: 50};

function draw() {
        if (ctx) {
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 200, 0)";
                ctx.fillRect(settings.x, settings.y, settings.width, settings.height);
                
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200, 0, 0)";
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
        };
};

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```